# Using generics with connect and when declaring a function in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, redux

I've recently started to use Typescript in my React projects and I'm struggling to understand generics inside of function declarations and the Redux `connect` function.

For example if I have the following code

```
interface WidgetStateProps extends BasicConfiguration {
  filters: Filter[]
}

class Widget extends React.Component<WidgetComponentProps, {}> {
 // my component
}
```

Now to my understanding, by declaring the generic, `<WidgetComponentProps, {}>` here, we have told typescript that we expect that the props our `Widget` component will receive will have the properties defined in `WidgetStateProps` and `BasicConfiguration`. Correct?

Great now moving onto an example of typing the connect function which is not necessarly in the same component as the one above.

```
export default connect<ModalStateProps, ModalDispatchProps, ModalOwnProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Modal);
```

In this connect function we have declared 3 generics. I'm confused on how these are typing `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchTopProps` when both of these return a function. Furthermore, what is `ModalOwnProps` typing?

The final things I'm having trouble understand revolves around using connect with higher order functions. Say I have the following connect function

```
export default function composeWidget<T extends WidgetStateProps, P extends WidgetDispatchProps, Q extends WidgetOwnProps>(Component, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps = undefined, mergeProps = undefined) { 

// some more code

  return connect<T, P, Q>(wrappedMapStateToProps, wrappedMapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(getComposedWidgetComponent(Component));
}
```

This is where everything starts to get really fuzzy. From this it seems that my first point is wrong. How could `T extends WidgetStateProps` define the shape of the first argument in the function which is `Component` when it clearly defines the second one.
Another confusion is what advantage do we gain by extending these various interfaces such as `WidgetStateProps`?